# Scala: Implicits + Override (+ReactiveMongo)

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Having code:

```
object MarketTrigger extends DbHandler[MarketTrigger]{
  implicit object BSONDateTimeHandler extends BSONHandler[BSONDateTime, DateTime] {
    def read(time: BSONDateTime) = new DateTime(time.value)
    def write(jdtime: DateTime) = BSONDateTime(jdtime.getMillis)
  }

  implicit val mtFormat = Macros.handler[MarketTrigger]
  override implicit val format = Macros.handler[MarketTrigger]
  ...
```

I've got the `Implicit org.joda.time.DateTime for 'value till' not found` error for the second implicit val, while first is okay. Kinda weird behavior for me. What's this about?